# No public IP after stop/start Amzon EC2 intance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elastic-ip

I have setup an AWS EC2 instance with a Elastic IP.

Static IP and Elastic IP both works fine (shows default NGINX page).

However when I **STOP** the instance and **START** back up, there is only a domain for `public IP` field

`http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/`

and above domain resolve to instance's public IP.

The problem is instance cannot make any outgoing requests (WGET, CURL, update, install packages ).

The reason is there is no **public IP** associated to the **instance private IP**. ( below image )

[image]

As you can see first 172.31.X.X does not have a public IP ( had before STOP/START ).

This happens from the first STOP/START instance.

However if I STOP/START without setting up an Elastic IP, AWS automatically associate a new public IP.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. You will need to re-associate the EIP when starting your instance.

Comment: Just finished writing bash scripts for `AWS CLI` commands for association and disassociating. Thanks mate!